# after Telnet Enable the Security level

Tags: windows-xp

After Enable telnet service in Windows XP PRO SP2, how affect the security level of system?

Will it be easier to infected virus or worm attack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost if you need remote access you should always consider SSH over telnet in almost every situation.  If you can't because of automated robots connecting over telnet only then you have to live with that, but other than that you should always use SSH.

By enabling telnet service you've provided yet another vector of attack for outside attackers.  Telnet has to known weakness because of the way it's architected, but there could be implementation defects specific to the windows service that could allow attackers to gain access.  You'll need to do some research to figure out what vulns exist on the telnet service for windows.

SP2 is pretty old so you'll want to apply all security patches so you're up to the latest.  Not doing so could allow an attacker thru another vector whether you're running telnet service or not.  In the big picture this question only makes sense to ask after you've upgraded your machine to the latest security patches.  Does turning on telnet service expose you to any known vulnerabilities for which a patch doesn't exist?  That would have to be researched.

Now there are some concerns you should have about using telnet.  One telnet doesn't encrypt passwords so if someone were to get behind your firewall they could potentially sniff the traffic going to that machine and get the root password because telnet sends passwords in the clear.  That could mean any computer on your network could see admin passwords.  Telnet should not be accessible to the internet because of this.  You should also be very careful about wifi access as well.  Make sure you are using WPA or some sort of protection from random people connecting into your network.  Otherwise anyone could see your passwords in the clear just by driving by.  So I'll assume telnet is turned on and is behind a firewall or VPN, not accessible to a public wifi.  If that's the case the potential threats are much lower since telnet can't be reached but by someone with access to your internal network.  At this point you've lowered your exposure to just the people who have access to that network.  That means how well does your VPN/firewall protect you?  If your telnet port is open on the firewall then you're not protected.  But, if it's safely behind one or both of those you could get away with running it.  But bear in mind that your security is hinging on the security of your firewall/VPN in that case.